# how do I download and install from the web to a Windows XP system

Tags: software-center

I have spent hours downloading Ubuntu and "installing", I don't know what!

Could you kindly suggest a web site and choices (if this is possible).

Comment: To help you choose which version would be best for your system, please can you let us know What system you use, RAM, graphics card and Hard Disk size.

Answer (score 0):

John by reading your question I understand that you are struggling to download and install Ubuntu. Visit the [Ubuntu Site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) then select the Ubuntu version you want to download. You will see you will be able to download the 32-bit and 64-bit version. The current stable release of Ubuntu is version 13.04. After downloading the ISO you can burn it to a DVD or make a boot able USB with Ubuntu. See this [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to see how to make a boot able Ubuntu USB